# Running java application on different JDK from original

Tags: java

I have developed a Java Application in Eclipse using JDK 1.7.0, the application runs and everything works as expected.

Now I would like to send the application to a colleague of mine who is using a different version of the JDK. He is using 1.6.x.

I am not interested in him opening up the application and debugging through it in Eclipse. I would only like him to run it. If I make a runnable `.jar` of the application and send that to him, would it work even though he has a different JDK installed on his machine?

Thank You.

Comment: For your JAR to run on his box he needs `JRE` (Java Runtime Environment) ver. 1.7.  He does not need `JDK` (Java Development Kit) just to run the byte-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if your colleague had a *newer* JRE than the JDK you used to compile it. All versions of JRE are backwards-compatible with all class files built with previous versions, but the opposite can clearly not work because new versions introduce new features. Your colleague will get an `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

However, it is easy to set up in Eclipse the target class version for your project: go to Project Properties, Java Compiler, and under JDK Compliance choose the version 1.6.

Needless to say, this will fail if your source code uses any features or library calls which the version 6 does not support.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile it using JDK 1.6 (or lower). Provided your code doesn't use features from Java 7, you won't have to change anything in your sources

Comment: With Eclipse you don't even need a JDK to compile code. It has its own compiler, which can be set up to produce any version of class files.